# Free Perl for IIS

Tags: iis-7, perl, cgi

I'd like to use [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) for website statistics. Is there some free Perl distribution that plays nicely with IIS 7?

This is what I've tried:

- Googling for `perl iis` yields a lot of tutorials, all of which refer to [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl). Alas, ActivePerl requires a $999/year license if you want to use it on an "external-facing" or production server (see Section 4b of the [ActivePerl Community License Agreement](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/license-agreement) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16107027/87698)).
- The [Perl download page](http://www.perl.org/get.html) also mentions [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and [DWIM Perl](http://dwimperl.com/windows.html), none of which mention IIS at all on their homepages. Since there are multiple ways to integrate software to IIS (ISAPI, CGI, Fast-CGI, etc.), I'd like something that explicitly mentiones how it should be integrated into IIS.

Are there other alternatives that I have missed?

Comment: Have you looked at standalone perl application servers, and using iis as a reverse proxy?

Comment: @Slicedpan: Not yet. Since it's just for a simple web statistics script, I'd like to keep the configuration as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pretty much any perl distribution you want.

Awstats is a CGI script - the configuration for a CGI handler for (e.g.) Strawberry perl is exactly the same as for ActivePerl - except that the path to the perl executable might be different.

[There is an article on HowToGeek that goes through setting up a Perl CGI handler in IIS7 step by step](http://www.howtogeek.com/50479/how-to-install-perl-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/), but the IIS documentation also covers this material.

Comment: Using Strawberry with the "usual" CGI setup works perfectly fine.